# How to find values that appear more than twice per day in a UNION ALL select in Db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need to check the account number which came in more than 2 times in any one day.

Below is my query, I'm getting the results where accounts number which came in more than 2 only from FAILURE not from SUCCESS. I need to get from both. Any helps are appreciated.

Sample data:

```
04/28/2020 123345 BERLIN 5645756768 SUCCESS
04/28/2020 123346 BERLIN 5645756768 FAILURE
04/28/2020 123344 BERLIN 5645756768 SUCCESS
04/28/2020 123344 BERLIN 5645756761 FAULTED
04/28/2020 123345 BERLIN 5645756763 FAILURE
04/28/2020 123346 BERLIN 5645756764 SUCCESS
04/28/2020 123347 BERLIN 5645756766 FAILURE
04/28/2020 123344 BERLIN 5645756763 TIME OUT
04/28/2020 123344 BERLIN 5645756760 PENDING

Query:

SELECT
    DATE,
    ID,
    NAME,
    ACCOUNT,
    STATUS
FROM
(
SELECT
    T1.DATE AS DATE, 
    T1.ID AS ID,
    T1.NAME AS NAME,
    T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS ACCOUNT,
    T2.STATUS AS STATUS,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE(DATE) CNT
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
WHERE STATUS = 'SUCCESS'
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.NAME,T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,T2.STATUS

UNION ALL

SELECT
    T1.DATE AS DATE,
    T1.ID AS ID,
    T1.NAME AS NAME,
    T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS ACCOUNT,
    T2.STATUS AS STATUS,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE(DATE) CNT
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
WHERE STATUS = 'FAILED'
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.NAME,T2.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,T2.STATUS
)
WHERE CNT > 2;'
```

Expected Output:

```
04/28/2020 123345 BERLIN 5645756768 SUCCESS
04/28/2020 123346 BERLIN 5645756768 FAILURE
04/28/2020 123344 BERLIN 5645756768 SUCCESS
```

Comment: We have no idea about your table data. It's better to simplify the question. Imagine, that you have a single table containing all columns needed. Please, provide sample data for this table and the result desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated the Question with sample data.

Comment: Your description contradicts with sample data provided and the result on it. There are only 2 rows (not more that 2 rows as you mentioned) with account `5645756768` on date `04/28/2020`, but these records are in the output. Why do you check the statuses of these rows? Must they be different to be in the output? What if you had X records of the same account on the same date with only one status? Too many questions...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the output.  irrespective of the status we need pull the transaction which came in more than two times in a day with same account number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why you need `UNION ALL` here, but let's presume, that you have some more complex checks with your real case.

```
WITH TAB (DATE, ID, NAME, ACCOUNT, STATUS) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('04/28/2020', 123345, 'BERLIN', '5645756768', 'SUCCESS')
, ('04/28/2020', 123346, 'BERLIN', '5645756768', 'FAILURE')
, ('04/28/2020', 123344, 'BERLIN', '5645756768', 'SUCCESS')
, ('04/28/2020', 123344, 'BERLIN', '5645756761', 'FAULTED')
, ('04/28/2020', 123345, 'BERLIN', '5645756763', 'FAILURE')
, ('04/28/2020', 123346, 'BERLIN', '5645756764', 'SUCCESS')
, ('04/28/2020', 123347, 'BERLIN', '5645756766', 'FAILURE')
, ('04/28/2020', 123344, 'BERLIN', '5645756763', 'TIME OUT')
, ('04/28/2020', 123344, 'BERLIN', '5645756760', 'PENDING')
)
SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, ACCOUNT, STATUS
FROM
(
SELECT 
  DATE, ID, NAME, ACCOUNT, STATUS
, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE, ACCOUNT) CNT
--FROM TAB
--WHERE STATUS IN ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE')
FROM
(
SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, ACCOUNT, STATUS
FROM TAB
WHERE STATUS = 'SUCCESS'
  UNION ALL
SELECT DATE, ID, NAME, ACCOUNT, STATUS
FROM TAB
WHERE STATUS = 'FAILURE'
)
) 
WHERE CNT>2;
```

The same result you get, if you just comment out whole `FROM (...)` and uncomment the commented out lines.
The result it is:

```
|DATE      |ID         |NAME  |ACCOUNT   |STATUS |
|----------|-----------|------|----------|-------|
|04/28/2020|123345     |BERLIN|5645756768|SUCCESS|
|04/28/2020|123344     |BERLIN|5645756768|SUCCESS|
|04/28/2020|123346     |BERLIN|5645756768|FAILURE|
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, But I need to check the statuses they are many different status apart from SUCCESS and FAILURE and we need also do unions all. So can you help me with union all here

Comment: I don't understand, why you do these `union all`. You can put them instead of `FROM TAB`: `FROM (SELECT ... WHERE ... UNION ALL SELECT ... WHERE ...)`. Use your checks inside.

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying,

Comment: It's time to provide more details on your sample data then. Show some example of checks you need to do.

Comment: I have updated the sample data with few more statuses, The first SELECT needs to select the SUCCESS transactions and and  second SELECT needs to select the FAILURE transaction, for this we are using union all because the reporting tool can choose the SUCCESS and FAILURE query.

Comment: I've updated the answer, but it's not clear still, why you need `union all` here.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark, it did exactly what I was expecting. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be much simpler to eliminate the UNION and just use the IN clause in your WHERE.

WHERE STATUS in ('SUCCESS', 'FAILED')

Comment: We can do that, for better understanding, I have put the simple query here. The requirement is bit different, there are couple more union all in this.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix - for your moe complex query you described - could be to separate the cnt columns.
use a cnt_success in the first with 0 as cnt_failure in the first part and vice cersa in the second.

So you could filter in the main / outer query to

```
cnt_success >=1
and cnt_failure >=1
```

This kind of problems could also be solved using a join.